# Output of this program is not getting accepted

Tags: c

I am trying to submit an answer given on codechef "https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW009"
this is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t, i;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    i=t;
    float qty[t], per[t], sum[t];
    do{
        scanf("%f %f", &qty[t-1], &per[t-1]);
        sum[t-1] = qty[t-1] * per[t-1];
        if(qty[t-1] > 1000 )
        {
            sum[t-1] = sum[t-1] - (sum[t-1]*10)/100;
        }
        }while(--t);
        do{
            printf("%f\n", sum[i-1]);
            }while(--i);
return 0;
}
```

It tells me again again that my solution is wrong and I am unable to understand it.I can't ask questions there as I have less karma.

Comment: Using `scanf("%d",&t);` tells it to scan the character string a the address of an int. That is unlikely to work.

Comment: so how should i put values in t?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Never store values for each test cases until told as sometimes the test cases may be large ,in place calculate and print output for each test cases. This may save memory ,time and confusion.
2. What could be done with few lines why to do with too much code and mess.

See this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int p,q;
        scanf("%d %d",&q,&p);
        float ans=(float)q*p;
        if(q>1000)
            ans-=(ans/10);
        printf("%f\n",ans);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the output should be in such way, thats why I stored all the outputs in some array, not in one by one case.

Comment: I am strictly following the way it said input and outputs must be. I am looking for some coding error in my code.

Comment: Try submitting my code, you cant get wrong ans...i also use codechef and have never stored output for every test case.

Comment: Second thing it strictly says input is integer and you have taken as float.This may mess with your product part `q*p`.

Comment: I used integers initially and again I tested with qty and per as integer and sum as float. It is always wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scan an int as a string. The sscanf() funtion scans a string according to the specified format string. This code could use more error checking.

```
$ cat FLOW009.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    char aline[100];
    int t;
    int quantity;
    int price;

    FILE *fh = fopen("FLOW009.txt", "rt");
    if (fh == NULL) {printf("open failed"); exit(1);}

    if (fgets(aline, 80, fh) != NULL) {
        sscanf(aline, "%d", &t);
        if (t < 1 || t > 1000) {
            printf("ERROR: Value of t, %d, is outside the range 1 to 1000\n", t);
            exit(1);
        }

        while (fgets(aline, sizeof(aline), fh) != NULL) {
            sscanf(aline, "%d %d", &quantity, &price);
            if (quantity > 0 && price <= 100000) {
                printf("%.6f\n", (float)quantity * (float)price);
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: Quantity and price are not within accepted limits.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    exit(0);
}
```